# Calculate closest days count, between each row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Given table like this (`dt`  column is unique ):

```
id | dt          | days_count
------------------------------
1  | 2015-06-01  |  NULL
2  | 2015-06-03  |  NULL
4  | 2015-06-09  |  NULL
```

I need calculate interval days count between closest dates and update retrieve result in column `days_count`, and calculation must start with latest date. that is, needed result is:

```
id | dt          | days_count
------------------------------
1  | 2015-06-01  |  NULL
2  | 2015-06-03  |  2
4  | 2015-06-09  |  6
```

I have 2 variant for this:

- variant 1

Using `PL/SQL FOR (SELECT ..) LOOP`, get every row, ordered by `dt desc` and calculate interval days between current row date and previous row  date.

- variant 2

  ```
  MERGE INTO mytable
  USING(
    WITH
    t1 as (SELECT id, dt,  row_number() over(order by dt) as rn from mytable),
    t2 as (SELECT  id, dt,  row_number() over(order by dt) + 1 as rn from mytable)  
    SELECT  t1.id, t1.rn,  t1.dt - t2.dt as days_count  from   t1
    left JOIN  t2
    on
    t1.rn = t2.rn
  ) day_interval
  ON (mytable.id = day_interval.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  mytable.days_count= day_interval.days_count
  ```

These variants works, but question is: maybe there is more effective way, for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never do it in **PL/SQL**, when you could do it in pure **SQL**.

You could simply do it using **LAG() OVER()** analytic function.

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (id int, dt date, days_count varchar2(4));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (id, dt, days_count)
  3           VALUES (1, to_date('2015-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL)
  4      INTO t (id, dt, days_count)
  5           VALUES (2, to_date('2015-06-03','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL)
  6      INTO t (ID, dt, days_count)
  7           VALUES (4, to_date('2015-06-09','YYYY-MM-DD'), NULL)
  8  SELECT * FROM dual;

3 rows created.

SQL>
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT id, dt, dt - lag(dt) over(order by dt) days_count FROM t;

        ID DT        DAYS_COUNT
---------- --------- ----------
         1 01-JUN-15
         2 03-JUN-15          2
         4 09-JUN-15          6

SQL>
```

**MERGE statement**

```
SQL> MERGE INTO t
  2      USING(
  3        SELECT id, dt, dt - lag(dt) over(order by dt) days_count FROM t
  4      ) day_interval
  5      ON (t.id = day_interval.id)
  6      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  7      t.days_count= day_interval.days_count;

3 rows merged.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        ID DT        DAYS
---------- --------- ----
         1 01-JUN-15
         2 03-JUN-15 2
         4 09-JUN-15 6

SQL>
```